# Are there any commonly used C++ compilers that would allow this syntax?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and trying to get [this](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/) open source program (developed for/in linux) to compile and run in xcode on OS X.

When I compiler and run the code I get a LOT of errors  (more than xcode is willing to count) like this `use of undeclared identifier 'x'` or this `use of undeclared identifier 'y'`

Here is a sample of the code throwing the error:

```
template<typename T>
struct TVector2 {
    T x, y;
    TVector2(T _x = 0.0, T _y = 0.0)
        : x(_x), y(_y)
    {}
    double Length() const {
        return sqrt(static_cast<double>(x*x + y*y));
    }
    double Norm();
    TVector2<T>& operator*=(T f) {
        x *= f;
        y *= f;
        return *this;
    }
    TVector2<T>& operator+=(const TVector2<T>& v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    TVector2<T>& operator-=(const TVector2<T>& v) {
        x -= v.x;
        y -= v.y;
        return *this;
    }
};
struct TVector3 : public TVector2<T> {
    T z;
    TVector3(T _x = 0.0, T _y = 0.0, T _z = 0.0)
    : TVector2<T>(_x, _y), z(_z)
    {}
    double Length() const {
        return sqrt(static_cast<double>(x*x + y*y + z*z)); //use of undeclared identifier x
    }
    double Norm();
    TVector3<T>& operator*=(T f) {
        x *= f;
        y *= f;
        z *= f;
        return *this;
    }
```

To my eye as an inexperienced C++ programmer, it looks like x and y are simply undeclared local variables. I can get the compiler to get rid of the errors by simply declaring the variables, like this...

```
struct TVector3 : public TVector2<T> {
    T z;
    T x;
    T y;
```

However, the sheer number of these errors makes me think that

1. There might be (reasonably common) versions of C++ compilers that allow you to declare a variable x as _x. That would explain why the source I downloaded has so many compiler errors.
2. Maybe I got a "bad batch" of the source and I should not waste my time getting it to compile because the source is screwy somehow.

Can an experienced C++ developer explain what might be going on?

Comment: `x` and `y` are presumably in `TVector2`.

Comment: @chris exactly - looks like not enough of the original code is being included in the compilation for it to succeed.

Comment: @chris you appear to have retired from answer posting to leisurely commenting only?? ;)

Comment: I'm not overly sure whether that's enough for the OP to solve the problem and commenting is enough procrastination on writing this proposal :p

Comment: @chris see the code i added

Comment: There's `template<typename T>` missing in front of `TVector3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `x` and `y` are data members of the base class, `TVector2<T>`.
- Because the base class is a type that is dependent on a template parameter `T`, it is *not* searched when looking up unqualified names.
- I believe MSVC used to compile this code, not sure whether it still does in C++11 mode. The reason is that MSVC didn't do name resolution properly in templates.
- The fix is usually to say `this->x` instead of `x`.

Comment: I've seen some references to `using x;` working for functions, would that also work for variables?

Comment: @Adam, `using TVector2<T>::x;` should.

Comment: @Steve: Visual Studio compiler is not doing two phase lookup *yet*, although I saw in a presentation that it is planned for the future, although most of C++14 features had higher priority than implementing two phase lookup.